# fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()) is making android app to crash

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, jobservice

This is the stack trace shown in Log Cat. I'm requesting location updates in a `JobService`:

```
fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
```

The app works fine if I comment this line. Please help me if anybody faced the same issue. I'm using `JobScheduler` and this crash is happening almost on every phone.

---

```
2018-11-23 14:36:06.071 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7y17ltextc/j7y17lte:8.1.0/M1AJQ/J730GMDXU5BRJ2:user/release-keys'
2018-11-23 14:36:06.071 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '7'
2018-11-23 14:36:06.071 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2018-11-23 14:36:06.071 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: pid: 26316, tid: 26326, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.goflytta.vendor.ops <<<
2018-11-23 14:36:06.071 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xa4169a29
2018-11-23 14:36:06.072 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     r0 cb89892c  r1 00002a84  r2 dfb11cb0  r3 dfb11ce0
2018-11-23 14:36:06.072 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     r4 dfb11cb0  r5 a4169a29  r6 dfb11ce0  r7 dfb21cfe
2018-11-23 14:36:06.072 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     r8 cb89892c  r9 dfb11cb0  sl 00000000  fp cb8989ec
2018-11-23 14:36:06.072 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     ip eaba8d74  sp cb898908  lr ea4522ef  pc ea44d798  cpsr a00d0030
2018-11-23 14:36:06.591 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00046798  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::release_object(android::sp<android::ProcessState> const&, flat_binder_object const&, void const*, unsigned int*)+23)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0004b2eb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+70)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00046eff  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+42)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00046ecd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000bc651  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_Parcel_destroy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long)+6)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0084df9f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x639000) (android.app.backup.FileBackupHelperBase.dtor [DEDUPED]+102)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 004127eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+226)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000b0251  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+180)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 002041f1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+224)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 001ff739  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+588)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 003f8741  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+184)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 003ffa94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 001eb55b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+142)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 001ff721  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 003f85d7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+254)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.592 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 003ffa14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 001eb55b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+142)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 001ff721  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 003f7737  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+482)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 003ff914  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 001eb55b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+142)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 001ff721  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 003f85d7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+254)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 003ffa14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 001eb55b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+142)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.593 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 001ff721  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 003f7737  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+482)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 003ff914  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 001eb55b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+142)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 001ff721  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+564)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 003f8319  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1080)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 003ffb14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 001e6dad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+340)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 001eb4a9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+92)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 003ed15b  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+934)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 00411af1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 0040d575  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 004126e5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 000b0227  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+138)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 00360139  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 00360ed1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+316)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 0037eaeb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+894)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 000487ef  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
2018-11-23 14:36:06.594 29436-29436/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 0001b34d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

Comment: Could you post some code? it is hard to suplpy a solution with only the log and no knowledge of the code.

Comment: @Manjunath I've copied that line of code from title to question body but it may be not enough, could you give a wider context?